# How do I check to see if the property of an element's innerHTML is null in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update the innerHTML of an element and I get the error "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null". I know why I'm getting that error, that is not the question. My question is, how can I check if the element's innerHTML property is null in JavaScript? I have read numerous web pages, stack overflow explanations, and I can't seem to check if that element's innerHTML is null. Everything I attempt still displays that error. Here is the most recent attempt:

```
if(typeof document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML !== null){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you know why you're getting the error? To be clear, the error is not telling you that that `innerHTML` is `null`; it's telling you that `document.getElementById('someElement')` is `null`. You're doing `null.innerHTML`, which is invalid.

Comment: Don't check for null.  Check its length property. `document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML.length`

Comment: Why are you getting that error?

Comment: It is throwing error because it can't find the DOM element.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" means that the object you are trying to access `innerHTML` on is `null`. You need to check *that* for `null`, not the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: I would say "I can't believe this question was down voted", but I've been on Stack Overflow long enough to know that it could happen very easily. Please keep in mind that often topics are very complex and do not require or deserve a down vote.

Comment: Except this topic was not very complex at all, what is why it received downvotes. You have to verify that the object you are trying to use is not null before you can do anything with its properties. Additionally, `typeof document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML !== null` is always going to evaluate to `true` even if `innerHTML` is `null`.

Comment: Herohtar, in your most recent comment's first sentence, I believe you meant to use the word "that" instead of what. We all make mistakes, and sometimes as I mentioned, topics can appear to be complex to someone, and that is the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check that the element is truthy and it's innerHTML is not null:

```
const myEl = document.getElementById('someElement');

if(myEl  && typeof myEl.innerHTML !== null){
    console.log("here");
}
```

Comment: `typeof myEl.innerHTML !== null` is always going to be true no matter what the content of `innerHTML` is.